# What is the geometric meaning of the variance of a multivarite normal distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

While studying a multivariate normal distribution with $(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma)$, For a beginner, it feels a bit difficult to picture what the shape of the variance of a multivariate normal distribution will look like. Hope to hear some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normal distribution over $n$ variables, you have an $n \times n$ covariance matrix, often shown as $\Sigma$, rather than a single variance. The value of $\Sigma[i,j]$ indicates the covariance between the $i$th and $j$th variables. Since $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$, the diagonal elements of covariance matrix shows the variance of each random variable.

Geometrically, It is difficult to imagine the probability distributions over more than two variables. For bivariate normal distributions (distributions over two random variables), if you draw the contours of the distribution, the elements of the covariance matrix determine the shape of the ellipses. For example, the ellipses are more elongated along variables with higher variances. Take a look at [this figure](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~kass/KEB/figures/bivariateNormalRev.png) for some intuitive examples.